# why do the Computability theory choose the natural number as the object of study？

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, predicate-logic, computability, computational-mathematics

I am wondering why the computable function is defined in the natural number set.Can people give me the answer or some resources that can solve my puzzle.

Comment: is there actually exist a computable function that take any argument （real number),but how can it be proved by turing machine  or lambda function model?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a few points to make, here:

First, the historical. The first real use of the idea of computable functions to prove a theorem was Goedel's use of them in his incompleteness theorem - that appropriate (primitive recursive) functions are representable. These functions, essentially, were functions *of natural numbers*, and so historically the first real context for computability is in the naturals.

Second, the applied. Any actual computing machine acts on finite strings of symbols in a finite alphabet - and we can biject these with the naturals in an intuitively-computable way. So we're "morally" still studying computability on the naturals.

Finally, the philosophical. A major factor in the mathematical significance of computability is the Church-Turing thesis; and, as a consequence, the fact that different models of computation yield the same notion of computable function. This *fails wildly* when we try to generalize to computability in broader contexts, e.g. computability of arbitrary sets, or of real numbers, or . . .

This is not to say that such "generalized computability theory" (usually called "generalized recursion theory," since most of the research on it predates the recursive/computable terminology change) isn't interesting; indeed, it's one of the things I'm *most* interested in! But computability on the naturals has a special role.

Comment: No relation to the fact that the set of [computable numbers](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computable_number) is countable, hence can be bijected to the set of natural numbers? Or is that already implied in your second argument?

Comment: @barakmanos I actually wanted to avoid talking about the computable real numbers, since already there we run into some issues - e.g. telling whether two computable reals are the same real is not, in general, computable. So already I'd consider that a context which is "less tame" than computability on the naturals.

Comment: @Lufamily - Comment: it is worth noting that Turing's [(1936) seminal paper](https://www.cs.virginia.edu/~robins/Turing_Paper_1936.pdf) opens with "The "computable" numbers may be described briefly as the *real* numbers whose expressions as a decimal are calculable by finite means." But then (quite obviously) it is introduced the "finite model" : "We may compare a man in the process of computing a real number to a machine which is only capable of a finite number of conditions".